# Is it possible to capture the url of a dragged browser tab?

Tags: javascript

More and more web browsers these days are supporting the tear-off and dragging of browser tabs.

Is it possible (using javascript?) to "catch" one of those browser tabs when it is released over an element on a web page and extract from that capture the URL of the page in that dropped tab?

I'm looking for a convenient way to add a URL to a page.  If I could enable a user to tear off a tab and drag it onto my page and thereby extract the URL that would be very slick.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this functionality to work?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to "capture" a dropped tab, because tabs, as different with text or images dragged, are treated as applications, not as information, and therefore if you drop a tab it will create a new window.

Comment: However, you can drag URL's into a window, and these can be captured. Unfortunately I don't know exactly how (unless you use a text field), so you'll have to find it out by yourself, but at least this is an alternative way you can work with an URL.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't drag a tab, you can drag a page's URL into a textbox. The way you do it is to drag the icon to the left of the address and drop it into the textbox of your choosing. If you want to drop it into a textbox in a different tab, you can drag the address's icon, hover it over the destination tab, wait for the tab to open, and then drop it into the textbox.